# cell value to change when hiding/unhiding specific rows in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, hide, rows

I am currently working with an excel sheet where I have grouped row 1-17 and have written a cell value in cell B18. I am wondering if there is a way to change the value in B18 when I click on the +/- sign when expanding/collapsing the rows.

For example: I want the cell value in B18 to be "Yes" when I click on the plus sign, and the value to be "No" when I click on the minus sign. Is there any way to do this?

Kinds regards,
Sandra

Answer (score 2):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

In general, **you should always provide some proof (code) of your previous attempts**, not only it helps us to understand better what you're trying to achieve, but also because of core principle behind this website is to help people with their code, not to do the coding for them!

---

Either way, I'll go out of my way and make an exception, given this is your first question and what you're trying to achieve is fairly easy to do.

Though my answers depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve though as it's not clear from your intial question.

1. If all the rows (1:17) are hidden

   ```
   Private Sub check_hidden_area()
     If Rows("1:17").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
       Range("B18") = True
     Else
       Range("B18") = False
     End If 
   End Sub
   ```
2. If at least 1 row in (1:17) is hidden:

   ```
   Private Sub check_hidden_area()
   Range("B18") = False
     For i = 1 To 17
        If Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
          Range("B18") = True
          Exit For
        End If
     Next i
   End Sub
   ```

---

**PS/Note**: The procedures listed do work, but as of now they don't auto-trigger (start) unless you launch them manually. Unfortunately it is impossible  to trigger the code on the "+/-" buttons.

1. Closest thing you can get to this being correct is to fire the macro on every worksheet change, this will however clog down the speed of your program and hog your CPU/Memory, especially if working with bigger data ranges

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target as Range)
      '...
      Call check_hidden_area
   End Sub
   ```
2. Alternatively just create a button (or something..) and call the procedure on `_Click` trigger, eg.

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click 
      Call check_hidden_area
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: What event will trigger these subroutines?

Comment: @MarcoVos That's up to the OP to decide, can be whatever you want. I don't see the point of declaring it to something specific in this case. The algorithm in question works, rest of it is "cosmetic" busy-work that is dependant on what the users wants to do with it. I don't really get your point here.Create a button for all I care

Comment: @ RawRplus  According to OP's question, the subs should be triggered when a group is collapsed or expanded. The problem is that there is no event for that action.

Comment: That is correct. Obviously though, I can't provide the code to fire on something, that has no triggerlistener on it, otherwise I would have included it in the code myself. Hence why I left the trigger unspecified and up to the OP to decide. i guess I'll edit the answer though to point this detail out as it's not necessarily common knowledge. Thanks